# how do you stop the battery animation, which appears when the phone is turned off and the cable is connected or d disconnected?

Tags: samsung-touchwiz

I am using rooted touchwiz on an s5.

Someone asked why disable them. I have a bike charger which occasionally puts out power for a few seconds and then cuts out repeatedly. So the animation comes on, which drains a little bit of battery, and then disappears. This cycle repeats, and results in the battery actually losing power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `/system/media` you should see some files whose names contain "battery" and end with `.qmg` or `.spi` (depending on your Android version). Moving those files elsewhere (for backup purposes do not just delete) should get rid of the animation.

Do back up before you fiddle with `/system`, though.

What I don't get is why you want the animations disabled. Does it do anything bad for you?

Comment: Just occurred to me, will this actually stop the screen from turning on altogether, which is what i need? Will try it and report back.